# automapper showing error "Specified cast is not valid."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, fluentvalidation

i am getting error while mapping DataTable with the model

here is my code

```
       if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (extension != null && extension.ToLower() != ".xlsx")
            {
                return "please upload file with extension .xlsx";
            }

            Stream stream = file.InputStream;
            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
            if (result.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                Mapper.Reset();
                Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, ExcelFeedbackRecord>();

                var results = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<ExcelFeedbackRecord>>(result.Tables[0].CreateDataReader());

            }
            return result.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
```

stack trace for error is below

> ```
>        [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]    DynamicCreate(IDataRecord ) +1673
> ```
>
> AutoMapper.Mappers.DataReaderMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context,
>   IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +433
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +347
>
> [AutoMapperMappingException: Trying to map System.Data.IDataReader to
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[SkillKindle.BLL.Feedbacks.ExcelFeedbackRecord,
>   SkillKindle.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. Exception of type
>   'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.]
>
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +433    AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type
>   sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts) +353
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(TSource source) +564
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(TSource source) +461
>   SkillKindleAdmin.Controllers.FeedbackController.ExcelUpload(HttpPostedFileBase
>   file) in d:\Skill
>   Online\trunk\SkillKindleAdmin\Controllers\FeedbackController.cs:57
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +107
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +286
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +655
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +326
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +317
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>   +219    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +275    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +328    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +492
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +261
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
>   +268    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
>   +461    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +235    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +328    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +492
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +262
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20()
>   +203    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +392    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +316    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +387
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +285
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +234
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +275    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +333
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +397
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +266
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +253    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +275    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +333
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +397
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +266    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +254
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +226
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +230
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +275    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +333
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +397
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +266
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +255    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +225
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +1086    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +603

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the columns returned by the datareader exactly match the property fields in the object ExcelFeedbackRecord, including casing?
If they are not, you'll have to add a configuration when creating the map.

Comment: First of all thanks for help and yes the columns exactly match the property field but it was not of string type. now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was that when we map DataSet with model, all property of model must be of string type only and then you can use CustomTypeConversion methods of automapper.